# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties error

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a Spring boot application. Where I have added this below dependency for Swagger API specification.

```
<dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>  
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>  
        <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

It is giving this following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class
> org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties

Could anyone please help to sort this ? Before add this dependency , project worked without any issues.

Comment: are you using spring-webflux?

Comment: No, I'm not using spring-webflux at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have Build Success in Maven clean, It was giving error while maven install. When I fixed that issue, this issue also got solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the the whole stacktrace, or create an issue on springdoc project with a sample minimal project to reproduce your error:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues